# A piece of diamond...

Tags: arithmetic

A piece of diamond accidently dropped and broke into 4 equal pieces. The value of the diamond varies to the cube of its weight. If the cost of diamond before breakage was $Rs. 64000$, find the loss after breakage.

My Attempt:

Let the weight of diamond before breakage be $x$ kg.

Price$=Rs. 64000$

Weight of each broken piece$=0.25x$ kg.

Now, what should I do on? Please give answer with clear explanation.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it indicate that any mass (weight) was lost as a result of the breakage. Hence we are left to conclude that there was no value loss either (or more likely, that you've misquoted the original question).

Comment: @barak manos, But I have exactly the same question?

Comment: Just to illustrate:  suppose it broke into two equal pieces.  Each would have half the weight, hence each would be worth $\frac 18$ of the original price.  Adding these would give us $\frac 14$ of the original value, so in this case  you lost $75\%$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information that you have not used is that of the price of the diamond varies to the cube of its weight. The formula that expresses this idea is:

$$\frac{\text{Price of diamond }A}{\text{Price of diamond }B}=\left(\frac{\text{Weight of diamond }A}{\text{Weight of diamond }B}\right)^3$$

Comment: If diamond A is the original diamond i.e before breakage then what do I use for diamond B? What values to be used?

Comment: I'd set diamond $B$ to be one of the pieces.

Comment: How did you use that formula? Or, why? Please explain?

Comment: @user354073 As you wrote, let the weight of the original diamond be $x$ and the weight of one piece be $0.25x$. Substitute these values on the right-hand side. You also have one price that you can substitute on the left. Now simplify the equation.